# Pivot flickering (WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivot, flicker

I'm developing a WP8 app, but the problem is that pivot pages sometimes flicker over the currently visible pivot. I tested this on a Lumia 1520, HTC 8S and the emulator. The emulator does not have this issue.
There is no redrawing event or so, no events that I'm using in code are triggered (I keep track of the in the debug console).

Anything I can do about this? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I can show you in this album: http://imgur.com/a/F1FOB. Apparently, it's all the controls in the pivotitems that suddenly flash on screen all together. The second image shows what it's supposed to look like. I have never seen a pivot acting like this..

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since you post your question...
I have the same issue on a WP8 app.
I can't provide you an exact answer for this, but I set all my pivot items Visibility to collapsed and on the SelectionChanged event from pivot control I set the selected item Visibility to Visible. 
With this I hope the behavior is no longer visible to the end user.

Did you find a way to solve this issue on your project?

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I didnt find any solution to this

Comment: I m facing the same issue on lumia 820 and lumia 520. It doesn't happen always. There are no calls that update the ui on the current pivot or the adjacent pivots. Yet flicker happens. And it is not consistent. Some sessions it doesn't happen at all while on others, few times and sometimes a lot.